Blazor Implementation of a parametrized component
I am starting to use Blazor to develop a web app.
I am kinda struggling on a problem that seems to be related to my lack of knowledge in the blazor way of doing things.
I have two files:
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, word</h1>
@foreach(var component in WidgetsEditor)
{
    switch(component)
    {
        case MarkdownEditor me:
            <h1> Premier</h1>
            <MarkdownEditor />
            break;
        case PythonInterpreter pi:
            <PythonInterpreter/>
            
            
            break;
    }
    
}

<button @onclick="addMarkdownEditor">Add a Markdown Editor</button>
<button @onclick="addPythonEditor">Add a Python Editor</button>
@code{

    
    List<Widgets> WidgetsEditor = new()
        {
            new MarkdownEditor()
        };
    
    public void addMarkdownEditor()
    {
        WidgetsEditor.Add(new MarkdownEditor());
    }
    public void addPythonEditor()
    {
        WidgetsEditor.Add(new PythonInterpreter());
    }
}

and the PythonInterpreter component

@inherits Widgets
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.25.1/full/pyodide.js"></script>
<input id="code" value="sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])" />
<button onclick="evaluatePython()">Run</button>
<br />
<br />
<div>Output:</div>
<textarea id="output" style="width: 100%;" rows="6" disabled></textarea>
<script>
  
  const output = document.getElementById("output");
  const code = document.getElementById("code");
  
  

  function addToOutput(s) {
    output.value += ">>>" + code.value + "\n" + s + "\n";
  }
 
  output.value = "Initializing...\n";
  // init Pyodide
  async function main() {
    let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
    output.value += "Ready!\n";
    return pyodide;
  }
  let pyodideReadyPromise = main();

  async function evaluatePython() {
    let pyodide = await pyodideReadyPromise;
    try {
      let output = pyodide.runPython(code.value);
      addToOutput(output);
    } catch (err) {
      addToOutput(err);
    }
  }
</script>
@code
{
    public int ident = 0;   

    [Parameter]
    public int Id{set;get;} = default!;
    
    
}


What I would like is to parametrize the html inside the Component, and to be able to give an ID to this.
My app is supposed to allow user to add blocks by clicking a button so I need an increasing ID.
If someone could help me out on this one, I think understanding this would enlighten my whole view on Blazor.
Thank you very much all
I tried to use Blazor TemplatedComponent, I tried to use RenderFragment but I failed to really understand how to use those.

BTW, the way you're doing Javascript is all wrong.  You should search for the documentation / video on how to do Javascript Interop in Blazor.  Short version: you don't declare <script> blocks in your markup.

I've added a minimal example answer for you.  Note that in C#, class instances are passed by reference, so any changes you make to the bound data are made to the original object.

You're not that far off, but you're thinking of Blazor as a tool to manipulate DOM objects.  You should think of the DOM as an expression of C# data, i.e. the way you're currently conceptalizing the relationship between object and data is backward.  Try something more data-driven:
Code.cs
namespace WidgetDemo.Code
{
    public class WidgetData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
    public class MarkDown : WidgetData
    {
        public string RawText { get; set; } = "";
    }
    public class PythonStuff : WidgetData
    {
        public string PythonCode { get; set; } = "";
    }
}

Home.razor
@page "/"
@using WidgetDemo.Code
@using WidgetDemo.Components.Editors //You'll have to change this.
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<button @onclick=AddMarkdown>+Markdown</button>
<button @onclick=AddPython>+Python</button>

@foreach (var item in EditorData)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case MarkDown MD:
            <MarkdownEditor MarkDown=MD />
            break;
        case PythonStuff PS:
            <PythonEditor PythonStuff=PS />
            break;
    }
    <button @onclick="()=>RemoveWidget(item)">X</button>
}
@code{

    List<WidgetData> EditorData = new();
    int IDcounter;

    async Task AddMarkdown()
    {
        MarkDown newMark = new();
        newMark.ID = IDcounter++;
        EditorData.Add(newMark);
    }
    async Task AddPython(){
        PythonStuff newPython = new();
        newPython.ID = IDcounter++;
        EditorData.Add(newPython);
    }
    async Task RemoveWidget(WidgetData WD){
        EditorData.Remove(WD);
    }
}

MarkdownEditor.razor
@using WidgetDemo.Code

<h3>MarkdownEditor (WidgetID: @MarkDown.ID)</h3>
<div>Enter your Markdown text here:</div>
<textarea @bind=MarkDown.RawText />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MarkDown MarkDown {get; set;}
}

PythonEditor.razor
@using WidgetDemo.Code

<h3>PythonEditor (WidgetID: @PythonStuff.ID)</h3>
<div>Enter your Python code here:</div>
<textarea @bind=PythonStuff.PythonCode />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public PythonStuff PythonStuff { get; set; }
}


This is a very good advice, I clearly get my misunderstanding and your comment helped me a lot, I figured everything out and it helped me for more advanced things I did after.
